# Is it possible to search a discussion board body?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

From my research I can set-up a search for a discussion board and effectively search of the discussion topic, but what about the body ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 content types make up a discussion board (or community site). They are **Discussion** and **Message**.

Discussion is the topic while Message are the replies of topic.

You can amend your search result webpart, change the query as follow:

```
{searchboxquery} ContentTypeID:0x012002* ContentTypeID:0x0107*
```

The search result web part come with a query builder to help you find the ContentTypeID. Or you may refer to some source like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms452896(v=office.14).aspx).

0x012002 = Discussion (Folder content type)
0x0107 = Message (List content type)